# Let $X$ be locally compact separable and $\mu_n\overset{*}{\rightharpoonup}\mu$. Then $|\mu|(O)\le\liminf_n|\mu_n|(O)$ for all open subsets $O$ of $X$

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, metric-spaces, weak-convergence

Let

- $X$ be a metric space,
- $\mathcal C_b(X)$ the space of real-valued bounded continuous functions on $X$,
- $\mathcal C_c(X)$ the space of real-valued continuous functions on $X$ with compact supports,
- $\mathcal M (X)$ the space of all **complex** Borel measures on $X$,
- $\mathcal M_{\mathbb R}(X)$ the space of all finite **signed** Borel measures on $X$, and
- $\mathcal M_+ (X)$ the space of all finite **non-negative** Borel measures on $X$.

For $\nu \in \mathcal M(X)$, let $|\nu| \in \mathcal M_+ (X)$ be its [variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_measure#Variation_of_a_complex_measure_and_polar_decomposition) and $[\nu] := |\nu| (X)$ its total variation norm.  Then $(\mathcal M(X), [\cdot])$ is a real Banach space. For $\mu_n,\mu \in \mathcal M(X)$, we define weak convergence by
$$
\mu_n \rightharpoonup \mu \overset{\text{def}}{\iff} \int_X f \mathrm d \mu_n \to \int_X f \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall f \in \mathcal C_b(X),
$$
and weak$^*$ convergence by
$$
\mu_n \overset{*}{\rightharpoonup} \mu \overset{\text{def}}{\iff} \int_X f \mathrm d \mu_n \to \int_X f \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall f \in \mathcal C_c (X).
$$

It has been shown that

> [Theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434003/complex-borel-measures-does-mu-n-to-mu-weakly-imply-mu-theta-le-li) Let $\mu_n,\mu\in \mathcal{M}(X)$ such that $\mu_n \rightharpoonup \mu$. Then for any open subset $O$ of $X$,
> $$
> |\mu|(O) \leq \liminf _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|\mu_n\right|(O) .
> $$

I would like to apply the same technique to prove that

> **Theorem** Let $X$ be locally compact **separable** and $\mu_n,\mu\in \mathcal{M}(X)$ such that $\mu_n \overset{*}{\rightharpoonup} \mu$. Then for any open subset $O$ of $X$,
> $$
> |\mu|(O) \leq \liminf _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|\mu_n\right|(O) .
> $$

My proof seems to be much simpler than the [original one](https://mathoverflow.net/a/434082/477203). It's likely that I made some subtle mistakes. Could you please have a check on my attempt?

---

**Proof:** We need the following lemmas, i.e.,

- [Lemma 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4570444/every-locally-compact-separable-metric-space-is-a-radon-space) Let $X$ be a locally compact **separable** metric space. Then $X$ is a [Radon space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure#Radon_spaces).
- [Lemma 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1914363/open-sets-with-compact-closure-containing-a-given-compact-set) Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. Let $K$ be a compact subset of $X$ and $U$ an open subset of $X$ such that $K \subset U$. Then there is an open subset $V$ of $X$ such that $K \subset V \subset \overline V \subset U$ and $\overline V$ is compact.

Let $\mathcal X$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $X$. By [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_measure#Variation_of_a_complex_measure_and_polar_decomposition), there is a measurable $g:X \to [0, 2\pi)$ such that
$$
|\mu| (B) = \int_B e^{i g} \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall B \in \mathcal X.
$$

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. By **Lemma 1,**  there is a compact subset $K$ of $O$ such that $|\mu| (O \setminus K) < \varepsilon$. By **Lemma 2**, there is an open subset $V$ of $X$ such that $\overline V$ is compact and $K \subset V \subset \overline V \subset O$. By [Urysohn's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma#Formal_Statement), there is a continuous $h:X \to [0, 1]$ such that $f(K)=1$ and $f(X \setminus V) = 0$. This implies the support of $f$ is contained in $\overline V$, so $f \in \mathcal C_c (X)$. Also, $|f| \le 1_{O}$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
 |\mu| (O) - \operatorname{Re} \int_O fe^{i g} \mathrm d \mu  &=  \operatorname{Re} \int_O (1-f)e^{i g} \mathrm d \mu \\
 &\le \left | \int_O (1-f)e^{i g} \mathrm d \mu \right | \\
&\le \int_O |(1-f)e^{i g}| \mathrm d |\mu| \\
&= \int_O |1-f| \mathrm d |\mu| \\
&\le |\mu| (O \setminus K) < \varepsilon.
\end{align}
$$

So
$$
\begin{align}
 |\mu| (O) - \varepsilon &< \operatorname{Re} \int_O fe^{i g} \mathrm d \mu \\
 &\overset{(1)}{=} \operatorname{Re} \lim_n \int_O fe^{i g} \mathrm d \mu_n \\
 &= \lim_n \operatorname{Re}  \int_O fe^{i g} \mathrm d \mu_n \\
 &\le \liminf_n \left|  \int_O fe^{i g} \mathrm d \mu_n \right| \\
 &\le \liminf_n  \int_O  |fe^{i g}| \mathrm d |\mu_n | \\
 &= \liminf_n  \int_O  |f| \mathrm d |\mu_n | \\
 &\le \liminf_n  \int_O  \mathrm d |\mu_n | \\
 &= \liminf_n |\mu_n| (O).
 \end{align}
$$

Notice that $(1)$ is true even if $fe^{i g}$ is complex-valued. The claim then follows by taking the limit $\varepsilon \to 0^+$.

Comment: (+1) Seems awfully simpler than the answer in MO. After a couple of reading all seems fine, but I think I should let it sit for a while before I get back to this.

Comment: @OliverDíaz I think my proof is what Giorgio meant in his/her [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434003/complex-borel-measures-does-mu-n-to-mu-weakly-imply-mu-theta-le-li/434082#comment1118051_434003).

Comment: @OliverDíaz Maybe I miss something, but Gioigio only posted a comment but no answer.

Comment: @OliverDíaz I'm sorry for bothering you too much... Have a good break.

Comment: Hi @Analysit, I see now a little flaw (I don't know how easy is to fix it) in your argument. It is right on the $\stackrel{(1)}{=}$ step. $\mu_n$ converges weakly to $\mu$ and indeed one can use complex test functions, the issue is that although $f\in C_{00}(X)\subset C_b(X)$, $fe^{ig}$ may not; hence $\lim_n\int_O fe^{ig}\,d\mu_n=\int_O fe^{ig}\,d\mu$ is not evident.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Please check my reasoning. We have $fe^{ig} \neq 0 \iff f \neq 0$. So $\operatorname{supp} (fe^{ig}) = \operatorname{supp} (f) \subset \overline V$ where $\overline V$ is compact. So $fe^{ig}$ is compactly supported.

Comment: no problem with the supports, it is just the potential lack of continuity of $fe^{ig}$. Under some conditions, continuity may be relaxed, for example of the st of discontinuities are a set of measure $0$, but not in general. I think there is still a way to fix the argument baby approximating $e^ig$ by functions in $C_{00}(X)$, after all integrable functions w.r.t. $|\mu|$ are in the closure of $C_{00}(X)$ under the $L_1(|\mu|)$ norm. Ij a way, that is what Iosif's argument does.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Ah now I got your point. Thank you so much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140519/discussion-between-oliver-diaz-and-analyst).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short proof of the main Theorem in the OP.
Let  $G$ be an open set in $X$. Since $|\mu|$ is a Radon measure, for $\varepsilon>0$ there is $f\in\mathcal{C}_{00}(X)$ with $0\leq f\prec G$ such that
$$|\mu|(G)-\tfrac{\varepsilon}{2}<|\mu|(f)=\int f\,d|\mu|$$
Since $|\mu|(f)=\sup\{|\mu(h)|:h\in\mathcal{C}_{00}(X;\mathbf{C}), |h|\leq f\}$ (see Proposition below), there is $g\in\mathbf{C}_{00}(X)$ such that $|g|\leq f$ and
$$|\mu|(f)-\tfrac{\varepsilon}{2}<|\mu(g)|$$
Hence
\begin{align}
|\mu|(G)-\varepsilon&<|\mu(g)|=\lim_n|\mu_n(g)|\\
&\leq\liminf_n|\mu_n|(|g|)\\
&\leq \liminf_n|\mu_n|(G)
\end{align}
since $|g|\leq f\leq\mathbb{1}_G$.

---

This is to show that

> Proposition: For any $f\in\mathcal{C}^+_{00}(X)$
> $$|\mu|(f)=\sup\{|\mu(h)|:h\in\mathcal{C}_{00}(X;\mathbf{C}), |h|\leq f\}$$

By the Radon-Nykodym theorem (all measures here are finite) there is $\phi\in L_1(|\mu|;\mathbb{C})$ with $|\phi|=1$ such that
$d\mu=\phi\cdot\,d|\mu|$. Notice that $|\mu(f\overline{\phi})|=\big||\mu|(f)\big|=|\mu|(f)$ and $|f\overline{\phi}|\leq|f|$. The only problem is that there is not reason for $\phi$ to be continuous. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $K_f=\operatorname{supp}(f)$  is compact, there is a relatively compact open set $U$ such that $K_f\subset U\subset \overline{U}$ with $|\mu|(U\setminus K_f)<\varepsilon$. Appealing to Lusin's theorem, there is $g\in\mathcal{C}_{00}(X;\mathbb{C})$ with $\operatorname{supp}(g)\subset U$ and such that
$$|\mu|(\{f\overline{\phi}\neq g\})<\varepsilon$$
and $\|g\|_u\leq \|f\|_u$. Suppose $g=g_r+ ig_i$, $g_r,g_i\in\mathcal{C}_{00}(X;\mathbb{R})$, and set
$$h=\max(-f,\min(g_r,f))+ i\max(-f,\min(g_i,f))$$
Then,  $h\in\mathcal{C}_{00}(X;\mathbb{C})$, $|h|\leq f$ and
$|\mu(h)-|\mu|(f)|=|\mu(h-f\overline{\phi})|\leq 2\|f\|_u\varepsilon$

Comment: Thank you so much! Basically, you have generalized [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967941/show-that-%ce%bcc-sup-substackf-in-c-b-f-le1-left-f-right-cc-0-mu/3967978?noredirect=1#comment9618976_3967978).

Comment: I have also posted my fix below. Could you have a check on it?

Comment: @Analyst: Everything looks fine now.

Comment: Essentially, Lusin's theorem helps us avoid the clever construction that is the cornerstone of Iosif's answer.

Comment: @Analyst: Sure, but by the law of the no-free lunch, one first needs to make an effort of going through Lusin's thorium instead of the effort of building things from scratch. Either way, the issue of continuity is resolved.

Comment: I have just asked [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434328/a-generalization-about-the-density-of-mathcal-c-cx-e-in-mathcal-l-p-x) about a possible generalization of your lemma.

Comment: I have not worked with the Bochner integral than much. But, the space space of elementary functions used to build it (functions of the form $\sum^N_{j=1}\phi_j\mathbf{u}_j$ with $\phi_j\in C_{00}(X)$ and $\mathbf{u}_j\in E$ are dense in $L_1(X,E)$. I think some conditions of separability may be needed to get stronger measurability of all functions in $C_{00}(X,E)$.

Comment: If $f$ is compactly supported and continuous, then its image is compact and thus separable. Then by [Pettis's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4546351/extend-pettiss-measurability-theorem-to-sigma-finite-measure-spaces) $f$ is strongly measurable.

Comment: There you go then. Like I said the elementary functions $\mathcal{C}_{00}(X,\mathbb{R})\oplus E$, i.e. functions of the form $\sum^n_{j=1}\phi_j\mathbf{u}_j$ are dense in $L_1(X,E)$ and so, $C_{00}(X, E)$ is dense in $L_1(X;E)$ since $\mathcal{C}_{00}(X;E)\oplus E\subset \mathcal{C}_{00}(X;E)$.... I will be in work meeting in a few minutes. We can still chat tomorrow if you have more things to discuss.

Comment: Maybe I miss your idea, but I'm interested in stronger result, i.e, $f \in \mathcal L_p$ can be approximated by $g \in \mathcal C_c$ such that $|g| \le |f|$. See you.

Comment: The $L_p$ space can be constructed similarly to the $L_1$ space starting with elementary functions $\mathcal{C}_{00}(X,\mathbb{R})\otimes E$ of the form $\Phi:=\sum^N_{j=1}\phi_j\mathbf{u}_j$ under the Daniell mean $\|\Phi\|^*=\big\||\Phi|_E\big\|_p$ ($1\leq p<\infty$). As usual in this constructions, the elementary set of functions is dense in $L_p(X;E)$ since the latter is the closure of the space of elementary functions under the DAniell pseudonorm $\|\;\|_p$

Answer (score 1):

As @OliverDíaz mentioned in a comment, my proof was wrong because $g$ is measurable but *not* necessarily continuous. Below is my fix.

---

Let $\mathcal X$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $X$. By [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_measure#Variation_of_a_complex_measure_and_polar_decomposition), there is a measurable $g:X \to [0, 2\pi)$ such that
$$
|\mu| (B) = \int_B e^{i g} \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall B \in \mathcal X.
$$

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. By **Lemma 1,**  there is a compact subset $K$ of $O$ such that $|\mu| (O \setminus K) < \varepsilon$. By **Lemma 2**, there is an open subset $V$ of $X$ such that $\overline V$ is compact and $K \subset V \subset \overline V \subset O$. By [Urysohn's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma#Formal_Statement), there is a continuous map $f:X \to [0, 1]$ such that $f(K)=1$ and $f(X \setminus V) = 0$. This implies the support of $f$ is contained in $\overline V$, so $f \in \mathcal C_c (X)$. Also, $|f| \le 1_{O}$.

> [Lusin's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4539421/confusion-about-a-proof-of-lusins-theorem) Let $X, Y$ be topological spaces where $X$ is Hausdorff and $Y$ second-countable. Let $\mu$ be a finite Radon measure on $X$ and $f:X \to Y$ measurable. Fix $\varepsilon>0$.
>
> - **weak version** There is a compact subset $K$ of $X$ such that $\mu(X \setminus K) < \varepsilon$ and $f_{\restriction K}$ is continuous.
> - **strong version** Assume moreover that $X$ is normal (*or* locally compact) and $Y=\mathbb R$.  Then there is a compact subset $K$ of $X$ and a continuous map $g:X \to \mathbb R$ such that $\mu(X \setminus K) < \varepsilon$, $f_{\restriction K} = g_{\restriction K}$, and $\sup_{x\in K} |f(x)| = \sup_{x\in X} |g(x)|$.
>
> **Note** The strong version is obtained from weak version and [Tietze extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem#Formal_statement).

By strong Lusin's theorem there is a compact subset $L$ of $X$ and a continuous map $h:X \to \mathbb R$ such that $|\mu| (X \setminus L) < \varepsilon$, $h_{\restriction L} = g_{\restriction L}$, and $\sup_{x\in L} |g(x)| = \sup_{x\in X} |h(x)| \le 2\pi$. Notice that $f \in \mathcal C_c(X, \mathbb R)$ and $fe^{ih} \in \mathcal C_c(X, \mathbb C)$ are both supported on $O$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
 |\mu| (O) - \operatorname{Re} \int_O fe^{i h} \mathrm d \mu  &=  \operatorname{Re} \int_X (1_Oe^{ig}-fe^{i h}) \mathrm d \mu \\
 &=  \operatorname{Re} \int_X \big [ (1_O-f)e^{ig}+f (e^{ig}-e^{i h}) \big ] \mathrm d \mu \\
 &\le \int_X |1_O-f| \mathrm d |\mu| + \int_X |f| \cdot |e^{ig}-e^{i h}| \mathrm d |\mu|  \\
 &= \int_{O \setminus K} |1_O-f| \mathrm d |\mu| + \int_{X \setminus L} |f| \cdot |e^{ig}-e^{i h}| \mathrm d |\mu|  \\
 &\le |\mu| (O \setminus K) + 2 |\mu|(X \setminus L) \\
 &\le \varepsilon + 2 \varepsilon = 3 \varepsilon.
\end{align}
$$

So
$$
\begin{align}
 |\mu| (O) - 3\varepsilon &< \operatorname{Re} \int_O fe^{i h} \mathrm d \mu \\
 &\overset{(1)}{=} \operatorname{Re} \lim_n \int_O fe^{i h} \mathrm d \mu_n \\
 &= \lim_n \operatorname{Re}  \int_O fe^{i h} \mathrm d \mu_n \\
 &\le \liminf_n \left|  \int_O fe^{i h} \mathrm d \mu_n \right| \\
 &\le \liminf_n  \int_O  |fe^{i h}| \mathrm d |\mu_n | \\
 &= \liminf_n  \int_O  |f| \mathrm d |\mu_n | \\
 &\le \liminf_n  \int_O  \mathrm d |\mu_n | \\
 &= \liminf_n |\mu_n| (O).
 \end{align}
$$

Notice that $(1)$ is true even if $fe^{i h}$ is complex-valued. The claim then follows by taking the limit $\varepsilon \to 0^+$.